# How can I find out what the seed was when creating a Random object?

Tags: .net, random

when you create a `.net` `Random` object with no parameter, you get, [as the docs put it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent
>   default seed value.

On the other side, you can specify the seed.

```
System.Random rand1 = new System.Random();
System.Random rand2 = new System.Random(222);
```

For `rand2` the seed is known. How can I find out the seed of `rand1` in order to obtain the same result at a different point in time?

Comment: Why do you want to obtain the same result at a different point in time? If it's for testing then just use the second constructor in your test rig and the first in your real application.

Comment: You could use the current milisecond as seed and save that the number.

Comment: Just checked the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca) and learned that this value is not stored inside the `Random` class, so you can't read it out via reflection. And to recalculate it from the instance's other fields seems very difficult too.

Comment: @ChrisF, I'm using it to generate some random based "art". If i like the output, I want to be able to reproduce it. As you might be aware, using the second constructor, give me the same result. Always.

I think I I can cheat and use two Random objects. First one to get a seed for the second. :-)

Comment: A non-crypto RNG can usually be cracked.  You just need to generate enough numbers in the sequence to allow you to solve the generator equation, and just run it backwards.  That would be a sledgehammer to crack a nut in this instance; ChrisF suggested the standard solution to this issue.

Comment: The closest to a solution was @hans-passant suggestion. Since it is not 100% accurate, I think, for the job at hand I can have the two Random objects approach.

Comment: @Adrian - he's not saying his solution is unreliable. He's saying that if you just accessed `Environment.TickCount` and then called the parameterless constructor (which itself calls `Environment.TickCount`), there's a chance that it would change between those two accesses. So you have to read the tickcount first and then *pass it as the parameter*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [default constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,52) of the Random class uses Environment.TickCount as the seed.  While you could technically use that property yourself to know the seed, it can't be 100.00% reliable since there is a very small chance that it changes between the two statements.

You'll have to do it like this instead so it is always safe:

```
int seed = Environment.TickCount;
System.Random rand1 = new System.Random(seed);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you specified the `System` namespace explicitly for `Random` but not for `Environment`?

Comment: It was just a copy/paste from the OP, no idea why he needed it.